# JUnit4 - format assert message _after_ failure detected

Tags: junit, junit4

Supposing I have non-trivial calculation function taking a bunch of parameters. And I have to test it for at least thousands of cases.
And I would like to have detailed message with all parameters values specified when certain case fails. I can format message string before check and pass it to assertXXX method. But it is very ineffective. My test spends most of its time formatting strings.

**My question is:**
Is there any smart way to format message string and pass it to JUnit after a test failure is detected and only then?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (foo.conditionThatCanFail()) {
  fail("condition failed for "+ foo);
}
```

As @bmargulies suggested, some assertion frameworks l(ike Hamcrest, Fest or Truth) will provide a nicely formatted failure message if an assertion fails.